# How to open the .vcf file after downloading in ReactJS app

Tags: reactjs, vcf-vcard

I have an ReactJS app which runs on a PC, but is mostly aimed at mobile devices. In this app I can download a .vcf (vcard, contact) file from the backend. I need to open this file immediately after loading (not in the browser, but through the built-in application on the phone). I found options for similar behavior on React-Native using the rn-fetch-blob library, but I need to implement this exactly on ReactJS. I can do it, or I need to rewrite everything under React-Native?